# Discord.js v12 Ban Command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I made a ban command for my discord.js v12 bot. However whenever I run the command I get an error.
Here is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: "ban",
    description: "Kicks a member from the server",

    async run (client, message, args) {

        if(!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send('You can\'t use that!')
        if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send('I don\'t have the right permissions.')

        const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);

        if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send('Please specify a user');

        if(!member) return message.channel.send('Can\'t seem to find this user. Sorry \'bout that :/');
        if(!member.bannable) return message.channel.send('This user can\'t be banned. It is either because they are a mod/admin, or their highest role is higher than mine');

        if(member.id === message.author.id) return message.channel.send('Bruh, you can\'t ban yourself!');

        let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");

        if(!reason) reason = 'Unspecified';

        member.ban(`${reason}`).catch(err => { 
          message.channel.send('Something went wrong')
            console.log(err)
        })

        const banembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Member Banned')
        .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .addField('User Banned', member)
        .addField('Kicked by', message.author)
        .addField('Reason', reason)
        .setFooter('Time kicked', client.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .setTimestamp()

        message.channel.send(banembed);


    }
}
```

This is the error I get whenever I run the command

```
 DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
    DICT_TYPE_CONVERT: Only dictionaries may be used in a DictType
        at RequestHandler.execute (/home/runner/SweatyBeautifulHelpfulWorker/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:170:25)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
      method: 'put',
      path: '/guilds/751424392420130907/bans/155149108183695360',
      code: 50035,
      httpStatus: 400
    }
```

I could'nt understand how to correct the problem in the code. I'm a bit new to coding. Can you please help me out!. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty easy to solve, all you have to to is pass the right amount of Parameters in the right way to the .ban function.

```
.ban({ days: 7, reason: 'your reason here' })
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban

Answer (score 2):

This looks like code from my video. It is a very simple error I made in the code. The .ban part should actually look like this:

```
.ban({ reason: 'your reason here' })
```

-thesportstacker