# ID Members Undefined

Tags: discord.js

Okay so I know I was on here earlier but now I messed something up trying to add another thing. Basically, I am getting an undefined error in the console because I am not sure how to write this in code for Discord.JS

Code:
`const id = message.id.members.first();`

Console Error:

````
(node:16412) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of undefined
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\Saman\Desktop\gban-bot\commands\test.js:12:39)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:16412) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:16412) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.```
````

Answer (score 0):

`message.id.members.first()` isn't a thing. `message.id` returns a snowflake .i.e. the id of the message that was sent. `message.member.id` also returns a snowflake/the id of the messaged member. In your case, if you want to get the member object itself, from a mention that is in a message,then you are looking for [mentions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions). So it's `message.mentions.members.first()` and would return the [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object itself. Using this, you can access the properties of GuildMember.

**EDIT**:

> Well what I am looking for is a way to ban by ID and I know this is a simple command but for some reason I can't figure out how to make it ban by ID and not a mention.

In order to ban them by id, first you need to find the GuildMember. There are 3 ways by which you can find a member. `find()` and `get()` using the collection of  [GuildMemberManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager). Or you can use `fetch()` using the `GuildMemberManager` directly (if the member is not in the collection). By doing this, you will get the `GuildMember` object. And you can ban him, by doing [`<GuildMember>.ban()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban)

`get()` and `fetch()` requires a Snowflake. i.e. an ID itself as a string. Whereas you need to provide a function inside `find()`. I'll link you to the djs documents for [these methods](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#managers-cache) if you still have any doubts.

Comment: Well what I am looking for is a way to ban by ID and I know this is a simple command but for some reason I can't figure out how to make it ban by ID and not a mention.

Comment: I just made some adjustments to the answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

You seem a little confused as to what you want to do. There are two things that are in a [message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) that contain some form of member.

The [member](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member) who send the message is always present. You can to access it, and the corresponding ID, like this:

```
let memberID = message.member.id;
```

Then there is the [member](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions) who got tagged in the message. Obviously that one isn't always present so you may need to add additional checks for that. You can access it like this:

```
let memberID = message.mentions.members.first().id;
```

Comment: Well what I am looking for is a way to ban by ID and I know this is a simple command but for some reason I can't figure out how to make it ban by ID and not a mention.

Comment: You would need to find the member object by ID first because you can only ban a member. So: ID -> member -> ban. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64315562/discord-js-v12-ban-command/64315660#64315660) on how to ban someone.